# Column check constraint cannot reference other columns

Tags: sql, oracle10g

```
CREATE TABLE acidtest (A INTEGER, B INTEGER CHECK (A + B = 100));
```

I want to create the above table with check constraint but it is showing following error

ORA-02438:Column check constraint cannot reference other column.

How to solve it....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this ....hope this will help  you

```
CREATE TABLE acidtest 
(A INTEGER, 
 B INTEGER null 
);

ALTER TABLE acidtest ADD CONSTRAINT my_constraint
CHECK (A + B = 100)

insert into acidtest values (15,16)
insert into acidtest values (25,75)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create table acidtest
( 
a integer,
b integer,
check(a+b =100)
)
```

Comment: What does this answer adds to the already accepted answer, other than a slightly different syntax?